# I am trying text recognition through oCR function. but it gives me error at first line that cant convert from cell to array

Tags: matlab, ocr

```
columnNames = string({'Aricept','Donepezil','Dementia','tpicerA','ROOMS','BRICK'});

stary=char(columnNames);
% Load an image
% I = imread('product_aricept_10mg.jpg');
% cd('E:\saba_study\7th sem\New folder\task3\*.jpg');
 [mat, dirc] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Select a  file');
I= imread( fullfile(dirc, mat) );
% Perform OCR
roi = [360 118 384 560];
results = ocr(I);
% disp(results);
disp(results.Text);

% Display one of the recognized words
% for i=1:results

word = results.Words{3};
disp(word);
com=char(word);
% end
% 
% Location of the word in I
wordBBox = results.WordBoundingBoxes(3,:);
figure;
Iname = insertObjectAnnotation(I, 'rectangle', wordBBox, word);
img=imcrop(Iname);
imshow(img);



x=validatestring(com,columnNames);
if(x==stary)
disp(x);
else
    disp('not recognized');
end

% Find characters with low confidence
lowConfidenceIdx = results.CharacterConfidences < 0.6;

% Get the bounding box locations of the low confidence characters
lowConfBBoxes = results.CharacterBoundingBoxes(lowConfidenceIdx, :);

% Get confidence values
lowConfVal = results.CharacterConfidences(lowConfidenceIdx);

% Annotate image with character confidences
str      = sprintf('confidence = %f', lowConfVal);
Ilowconf = insertObjectAnnotation(I, 'rectangle', lowConfBBoxes, str);

figure;
imshow(Ilowconf);
title('you need to take this medicine 3 times a day');`
```

I want that when any image is selected and ocr function is applied the value returned by this is compared through string value using validate property to check if it matches the value then display value else return no matching value. Please help me how can I handle if condition

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
names={'Aricept','Donepezil','Dementia','tpicerA','ROOMS','BRICK'}
```

Is already a cell, and almost no operator in matlab can take a cell as input.
However

```
string(names{1})
```

is a valid input, since names{1} contains a string.

Comment: yes, you probably have to add some loops in the code. everytime you need one of the strings inside the cell, call it with stary{i}